# conversion between UINT and LPCWSTR in c++

Tags: c++, string-conversion

How can I get the string representation (as `LPCWSTR`) of a variable of type `UINT`?

Comment: `UINT` is a typedef for an `unsigned int`, and `LPCWSTR` is a 32-bit pointer to a string of 16-bit characters (long-pointer-to-constant-wide-character-string aka `const wchar_t*`). Are you trying to turn the `UINT` into a string, or do you actually mean to cast the `UINT` into a pointer to string?

Comment: no no, i meant string, not a pointer

Comment: You didn't answer @birryree's question -- are you trying to get the string representation of an integer (like "itoa")?

Comment: @birryree: There is nothing necessarily 32bit about it. It could easily be 64bit.

Comment: @DeadMG - I took that explanation directly from an MSDN site, probably a little outdated (pre-x64).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `LPCWSTR` is a constant `LPWSTR`, which is a pointer to a wide-character string. You should  use a `std::wstringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

UINT number = 42;
std::wstringstream wss;
std::wstring str;

wss << number;
wss >> str;
LPCWSTR result = str.c_str();
```

Comment: May want to mention you need to `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: is there any other way besides using streams? just curious.

Comment: @bobbymcr Thanks. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Abulali: the C++ way is to use string streams. The C way is to use `_itow` as @RobinCaron shows in his answer (except you should actually use `_itow_s` to avoid buffer overruns). If you're using C++, use C++...

Comment: *"A LPCWSTR is a constant LPWSTR"* -- Not exactly.  A constant `LPWSTR` would be `wchar_t * const`,  but `LPCWSTR` is `const wchar_t *`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, I did not know how to word it. I originally worded it "a pointer to a constant LPWSTR" before I edited it. Is that correct?

Comment: @Marlon: No, that's not correct either, because that would be `wchar_t * const *`.  No qualification on `LPWSTR` will get you the equivalent of `LPCWSTR`, the typedef cements it.

Answer (score 1):

Try _itow.  It takes an unsigned integer, the address of a wide character buffer and what base to use for the conversion.

Here's an example:

```
UINT x = 1000245; 
LPWSTR y = (LPWSTR)malloc(30); 

_itow(x, y, 10);
```

Comment: For MSVC, you should use the safe version of `_itow` to avoid buffer overruns, `_itow_s`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: i get this error: main.cpp(45): error C2660: '_itow_s' : function does not take 3 arguments

Comment: FWIW: to use _itow_s you'd need to pass in the size of the buffer.  From above the size would be 15 (30/2 -- 30 is the buffer size, 2 being sizeof(wchar_t)) -- so the call would be _itow_s(x, y, 15, 10).

Comment: I just noticed that you want a C++ way.  You'd probably want to avoid using malloc in that case.  You can use new like so: LPWSTR y = new wchar_t[15];  I apologize for flipping this around -- I didn't pay attention to see if you wanted a C or C++ answer.